# How to get parent DataContext in DataTemplateSelector in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: data-binding, windows-phone-8.1, parent, datatemplateselector

I'm using DataTemplateSelector in Window Phone 8.1 application and want to add specific DataTemplate for parent DataContext of my ContentControl. But container.Parent is always null in SelectTemplateCore. Could you help me with desired solution?

```
public class EmptyDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate EmptyDataTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate BaseDataTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate ExportedDataTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item == null || (item is string && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((string)item)))
        {
           var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(container); //always null
           if ((parent as Grid).DataContext is Trip && ((parent as Grid).DataContext as Trip).IsExported)
               return ExportedDataTemplate;
           return EmptyDataTemplate;
        }            
        return BaseDataTemplate;
    }
```

EmptyDataTemplateSelector is using for simple ContentControl inside a grid.